# Get unique strings from array of array of objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array which contains arrays of objects. I want to get the unique property values from the array. E.g.

```
var array =     [
  [
    {
      a: 'ggg'
    },
    {
      a: 'kkk'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      a: undefined
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      a: 'ddd'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      a: 'ggg'
    }
  ]
];
```

Would return:

```
['ggg', 'kkk', 'ddd']
```

Im using the underscore library, heres what I tried:

```
var list = _.reduce(arr, function(memo, v, k) {
      memo.concat(_.pluck(v, 'a'));
    return memo;
}, []);

console.log('list is ', list);

console.log(_.uniq(list));
```

But its not working. The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s8uqun9s/2/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using Underscore's [**flatten**](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten), [**reject**](http://underscorejs.org/#reject), [**pluck**](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) and [**uniq**](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq):

```
var result = _.chain(array)
    .flatten()
    .pluck('a')
    .reject(_.isUndefined)
    .uniq()
    .value();
```

Comment: Very nice. Leaves undefined though. Adding .filter(Boolean); to the end will filter out falsey values

Comment: Oops, thanks. Added a `reject(_.isUndefined)` to get rid of those pesky undefineds

Answer (score 4):

With ES6, you could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
var array = [[{ a: 'ggg' }, { a: 'kkk' }], [{ a: undefined }], [{ a: 'ddd' }], [{ a: 'ggg' }]],
    set = new Set();

array.forEach(a => a.forEach(b => b.a && set.add(b.a)));
console.log([...set]);
```

Traditional with an object.

```js
var array = [[{ a: 'ggg' }, { a: 'kkk' }], [{ a: undefined }], [{ a: 'ddd' }], [{ a: 'ggg' }]],
    set = Object.create(null);

array.forEach(function (a) {
    a.forEach(function (b) { 
        b.a && (set[b.a] = true);
    })
});
console.log(Object.keys(set));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over it and manually create an array

```js
var array = [
  [{
    a: 'ggg'
  }, {
    a: 'kkk'
  }],
  [{
    a: undefined
  }],
  [{
    a: 'ddd'
  }],
  [{
    a: 'ggg'
  }]
];

var result = [];
array.forEach(function(a){
  a.forEach(function(obj){
    if(result.indexOf(obj.a) < 0 && obj.a)
      result.push(obj.a)
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [
  [{
    a: 'ggg'
  }, {
    a: 'kkk'
  }],
  [{
    a: undefined
  }],
  [{
    a: 'ddd'
  }],
  [{
    a: 'ggg'
  }]
];

var values = [];

array.map(function(item) {
  return item.map(function(item2) {
    if(item2.a)
      values.push(item2.a);
  });
});

values = values.filter(function(v, i) {
  return values.indexOf(v) == i;
});

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some others have anwsered now, but here's now I did it:

https://jsfiddle.net/uc0vot3n/

```js
var array =     [
  [
    {
      a: 'ggg'
    },
    {
      a: 'kkk'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      a: undefined
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      a: 'ddd'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      a: 'ggg'
    }
  ]
];

var uniq = [];

array.map(function(obj){
  obj.map(function(item){
        if (uniq.indexOf(item.a) === -1 && item.a){
        uniq.push(item.a);
      }
    });

});

console.log(uniq);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution to the norm...it doesn't use indexOf so I believe it would be a little more efficient in large datasets, since we don't have to search the unique array each time we add an item.

```js
var array =     [
  [
    {
      a: 'ggg'
    },
    {
      a: 'kkk'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      a: undefined
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      a: 'ddd'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      a: 'ggg'
    }
  ]
];
var map = {};
var uniq = [];

array.forEach(function(items){
    items.forEach(function(item){
        if(item.a) {
            map[item.a] = true;
        }
    });
});

for(var i in map){
    if(map.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        uniq.push(i);
    }
}

console.log(uniq);
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing you run babel or a recent version of nodejs, you don't need lodash or underscore for that.

The following example relies on `a` always being a string so it can be used as an object key.

```js
var arr = [
  [{
    a: 'ggg'
  }, {
    a: 'kkk'
  }],
  [{
    a: undefined
  }],
  [{
    a: 'ddd'
  }],
  [{
    a: 'ggg'
  }]
];

var list = Object.keys(
  arr.reduce(function flatten(flattened, subarr) {
    return [...flattened, ...subarr]
  }, [])
  .filter(function hasA(obj) { return obj.a != null })
  .reduce(function putAintoAccumlator(accumulator, obj) {
    return {
      ...accumulator, [obj.a]: true
    }
  }, {})
)
console.log(list)
```

Another solution would be to use [ES6 `Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).